# An unfortunate accidental up-vote

Tags: support, voting

I accidently rated [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16633/drinking-and-math-closed) up, and can't remove it (due to insufficient reputation, I think). Is there anything I can do? I feel very foolish at the moment, to say the least!

I also wasn't sure what to tag this as. I'm sure it's not a bug but it seemed most fitting with a perfunctory glance at the list.

Comment: Your vote is locked unless the question is edited, if memory serves. Your vote is also invisible, so you shouldn't feel foolish!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a five minute undo window to change a vote; after that the vote is locked in unless the underlying post is edited.

This is because there are a lot of exploits around long vote undo windows, or changing votes frequently.

Comment: Have those exploits actually been seen in nature?

Comment: @mariano where there are "no elephants" signs you can generally safely assume there have been problems with elephants.

Comment: with that philosophy, I guess we are all fortunate that you are here and not turned to politics, for example, or organizing Inquisitions!